# Elasticsearch - Mapping conflict error upgrading from 1.5 to 2.0

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

When trying to start the master node of my cluster, just after the upgrade from 1.5 to 2.0 (yeah, that's a big jump), I get this error log:

```
[2015-11-03 18:15:10,948][ERROR][gateway                  ] [mon-01] failed to read local state, exiting...
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to upgrade the mappings for the index [logstash-2015.10.18], reason: [Mapper for [timestamp] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:
[mapper [timestamp] cannot be changed from type [date] to [string]]]
```

Unfortunately, I don't have the detailed description of the field or the relevant analyzer configuration for the field, but as its name states, it's a timestamp from logstash, so it should look like one of these:

- "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z"
- "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
- "HH:mm:ss"
- "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS ZZ"
- "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSSZZ"
- "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"

The log ends with this:

```
[2015-11-03 18:15:11,383][ERROR][bootstrap                ] Guice Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to upgrade the mappings for the index [logstash-2015.10.18], reason: [Mapper for [timestamp] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:
[mapper [timestamp] cannot be changed from type [date] to [string]]]
Likely root cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapper for [timestamp] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:
[mapper [timestamp] cannot be changed from type [date] to [string]]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldTypeLookup.checkCompatibility(FieldTypeLookup.java:117)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.checkNewMappersCompatibility(MapperService.java:345)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.merge(MapperService.java:296)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.merge(MapperService.java:242)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataIndexUpgradeService.checkMappingsCompatibility(MetaDataIndexUpgradeService.java:329)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataIndexUpgradeService.upgradeIndexMetaData(MetaDataIndexUpgradeService.java:112)
    at org.elasticsearch.gateway.GatewayMetaState.pre20Upgrade(GatewayMetaState.java:226)
    at org.elasticsearch.gateway.GatewayMetaState.<init>(GatewayMetaState.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at <<<guice>>>
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:198)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:145)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:170)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:270)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
```

And the node shuts down..

I have carefully read issues [#13169](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/13169) and [#13345](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/13345), but none of these helped me, the node keeps failing to start.

i know that [changing the mappings](https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime) is easy when ES is up, but I'm kind of stuck here.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from an Elasticsearch dev, it looks like a problem in my data, and not in ES itself: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14491

> your logstash-2015.10.18 index has a timestamp field which is mapped
>   as a string on one type and as a date on another type, which is
>   something that elasticsearch can't cope with. In elasticsearch 1.x
>   this issue would be silent and only trip when trying to
>   search/sort/aggregate on a field. In Elasticsearch 2.0, we detect
>   these inconsistencies more proactively.

The definitive answer is here: https://www.elastic.co/blog/great-mapping-refactoring

> You will not be able to upgrade indices with conflicting field
>   mappings to Elasticsearch v2.0.
>
> If the data in these indices is no longer needed, then you can simply
>   delete the indices, otherwise you will need to reindex your data with
>   correct mappings.

This tool may help to extract data and reimport it: https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump